# how to create csv from list contain list as headers?

Tags: python, csv

I want to create csv file with list of lists. Below is the example.

```
l = [['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'], ['name1','name2','name3', 'name4' ]]

headers = ['profile', 'name']
```

in above example, 1st list should update all rows for profile header and second list should update all rows for name column.

Comment: You need a CSV writer. It is [well-documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: its better practice to do it like `{header:[data], header2:[data']}`

Comment: with the way CSV files are structured in the background, each row is a list of things separated by CSVs (comma separated values) and then at the end of that first row, you can fill in the next row by starting a new line and then preceding to add more comma-separated values for that. to leave a column blank, simply put nothing between the preceding command and the closing comma for that column space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a cleaner way to iterate over a list of lists, but this is a start

```
import csv 

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
  w = csv.writer(f)
  w.writerow(headers)
  for p,n in zip(l[0], l[1]):
    w.writerow([p,n])
```

#### Output

```
profile,name
test1,name1
test2,name2
test3,name3
test4,name4
```

Comment: `w.writerows(zip(*l))` ?